# Error al rellenar array con numeros y recorrerlo con for each en java

Tags: java, array, java-swing, bucle-for, foreach

Estoy intentando crear un array en java rellenarlo con números digitados a través de un input pane para luego recorrerlos con un for each e imprimirlos en consola, el código a primera vista no tiene error, me da error al compilarlo. Agradecería que me eduquen un poco para aprender. el código es el siguiente:

```
package ejercicio5arraysats;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejercicio5ArraysATS {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arreglo = new int[5];
    int numero = 0; 




   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor digite los numeros");

        for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {

            arreglo[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserte el numero: " + numero));

            numero ++;

        }

       for(int i : arreglo) {

           System.out.println("El numero es: " + i + "\n");

  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu array esta dimensionado para contener 5 elementos:

```
 int[] arreglo = new int[5];
```

Los elementos serían 5 iniciando con el indice 0 y terminando con el indice 4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto el problema es que tratas de insertar más elementos, desde 0 a 5 serían 6 elementos lo cual es incorrecto:

```
 for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
```

debes cambiar tu `for` para permitir únicamente 5 elementos iniciando desde 0 a 4:

```
 for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Estuve tiempo buscando el error, es increíble el haber tenido un error tan tonto y no darme cuenta...